# CSS: Replacing a text on hover, but smooth transition to the new text does not work?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

**The scenario:**

If a user hovers over a text (e.g. an h1-tag), it should change to a new text. The new text should appear smoothly.

**What I've done so far:**

I was able to replace a text with a new one with the "display:none" and the "content: 'This is the new text' "-property. My problem is that the new text does not appear smoothly (it does not fade in/transitions). 
I've also tried to use opacity, but it doesn't replace my old text (instead it just disappears and the new text appears next to it).

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33eLvvm4/2/) and code snippet:

```css
.my_div {
  background-color: red;
}
.my_div:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.my_div:hover .title span {
  display: none;
}
.my_div:hover .title:after {
  content: "A wild text appears";
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div">
  <h1 class="title"><span>This is the old text</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: do u have anyoutput how it should be?

Comment: As you can see in the code snippet the background color transitions smoothly but the text just "pops up" immediately. The text should fade in (slowly) just like the background changes its color.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a really simple sample

(This hidden snippet use pseudo elements instead of the visible's inner `div`'s)

```css
div, div:after, div:before {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black
}

div:after {
    content: "New";
    opacity: 0;
}
div:before {
    content: "Old";
    opacity: 1;
}

div:after, div:before {
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.wrap:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
.wrap:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
</div>
```

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black
}

.new {
    opacity: 0;
}

.old, .new {
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.wrap:hover .old {
    opacity: 0;
}
.wrap:hover .new {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="new">New</div>
<div class="old">Old</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this elegant solution. However it won't work if you don't want to specify background colors (-> then the old and new text will just overlap). https://jsfiddle.net/pq3x0qvc/ . Do you also have a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Yes, transparent would be perfect!

Comment: @user3385759 Updated!

Answer (score 8):

OK, so first part, you cannot animate the display property, you need a work-around. To do this we fall back to what we can animate, opacity and width/height

For what you are trying to accomplish, I'd use two spans inside the `<h1>` - one with each text version. Since spans are inline elements we give them `display: block` so we can control there dimensions more cleanly.

```css
.my_div {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.my_div:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.old-text,
.new-text {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.old-text {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  width: auto;
}
.new-text {
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.my_div:hover .old-text {
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
}
.my_div:hover .new-text {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div">
  <h1 class="title">
        <span class="old-text">This is the old text</span>
        <span class="new-text">A wild text appears!</span>
     </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This is even working if you don't want to specify a background color: https://jsfiddle.net/89vjkbzf/

Comment: I think this is a better approach than in the accepted answer. The text will still be in HTML as opposed to being in CSS so better for SEO. Also, the original text is hidden without transition, I changed the `old-text` element transition to only change its opacity and set position absolute: `opacity: 0,position: 'absolute'`. So it now work both ways

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered, but I think the best approach would be to use a pseudo element.
It's very simple and clean.
**BUT:** you lose the transition effect.

```css
.MySpecialTag:before
{
    content: "The old text";
}
.MySpecialTag:hover:before
{
    content: "The new text";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="MySpecialTag"></h1>
```

Comment: thanks, however if we use a pseudo element, is it also possible to transition it/fade the new text in? That was actually my main problem :) (And I've initially used a pseude-element as well, see my code snippet).**Edit** Ah, you edited your answer, hehe.

Comment: not in an easy way, because the `content` property doesn't works with `transition`. (it;s not a numerical value)

Comment: @avrahamcool You were on the right track ... I made this based on your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/pq3x0qvc/2/

Comment: @LGSon Like I said, `not in an easy way`... +1 from me.