# Replacing text after hover CSS

Tags: css, text, hover

I wanted to replace my text after hovering on it for a different one.

I'm attaching a code I've written as for now.

Probably I need a command I don't know...

Thank you for help.

```
     span:hover
     {
         font-size: 20px;
         transition: font-size .4s ease-in-out;
     }

     span::after
     {
         content: hide;
         visibility: hidden;
         transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
         content: 'Zima';
         opacity: 0;
     }
     span:hover::after
     {
         visibility: visible;
         opacity: 1;
     }
```

Comment: Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057737/css-replacing-a-text-on-hover-but-smooth-transition-to-the-new-text-does-not-w

Comment: The new text is upon the old one :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.label:after{
    content:'ADD';
}
.label:hover:after{
    content:'NEW';
}
```

```html
<span class="label"></span>
```

Comment: @oldo4 Awesome, glad to help!